# How to obtain test case name in Visual Studio Test Framework at runtime?

Tags: unit-testing, mstest

How can i get test case name during runtime in Visual Studio Test Framework?

I am using VS 2010 to write my unit test cases and I need to get test case name during Test Init for each test and save those in file.

Sample Code

```
[TestInitialize()]
public void MyTestInitialize() 
{
    string testCaseName = //Find way to get test case name of this test case
    //Save Logic with TestCaseName

}

[TestMethod]
public void T_1()
{
  //Execute Test
}

[TestMethod]
public void T_2()
{
  //Execute Test
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is not 100% clear, but does the TestName property of the TestContext instance for your class give you what you need?

Comment: Yes it does :) I was so dump,  couldn't figure out that much

Answer (score 0):

It is simple enough this.TestContext.TestName gives test case Name